Excel multidimensional count
Is the below possible in Excel for Mac?
I have a sheet containing 10s of 1000s of records and I need to repeatedly do analysis on it to count the total incidence of substrings within different samples of the data.
I need to know the:
total count of records:

where Record.FreeTextNotes contains any of a list of substrings
AND
where the Record.Category = the selected category/s; AND the Record.SubCategory = the selected subcategory/s

(I need to avoid double counting records where FreeTextNotes contain more than one of the substrings)
The substrings are variable and depend on the category being analysed and there could be up to 20 of them.



ID
Category
Subcategory
FreeTextNotes




1
Category 1
Subcategory 1.1
Lorum XYYZ ipsum


2
Category 1
Subcategory 1.1
Lorum Z ipsum


3
Category 2
Subcategory 2.1
Lorum ipsum ZX


4
Category 3
Subcategory 3.1
X Lorum ipsum Z


5
Category 3
Subcategory 3.1
Lorum ipsum


---
--------
--------



6
Category 1
Subcategory 1.1
Null


7
Category 1
Subcategory 1.2
Lorum X ipsum


8
Category 2
Subcategory 2.1
LXrum iYsum XYZ


9
Category 4
Subcategory 4.1
X


10
Category 3
Subcategory 3.1
XoYum Zpsum



So in in the table above, using the search criteria of Category 1, Subcategory 1.1 + Category 2, Subcategory 2.1 where FreeTextNotes contain "X" or "Y".  Answer should be: 3
I'm a reasonably advanced Excel user and have looked into pivot charts, slicers, COUNTIFS, but this is beyond me.
This is as far as I've got which finds 2 substrings at a time, but doesn't restrict the results by category and subcategory.
=SUMPRODUCT(--((ISNUMBER(FIND(SubstringCellRef1,_FreeTextNotes)) + ISNUMBER(FIND(SubstringCellRef2,_FreeTextNotes)))>0))


Questions - how does the data arrive to the query - and in what form? Do you have a list of substrings that you are searching for? Is this a one off list (IE I'm just looking for Cat1-Subcat1.1)s or is there a specific combination of category/subcategories that you'd like?

The data is manually imported into the .xls file from a csv download (via PowerQuery). The category and subcategory lists don't vary.  The keyword substrings do.

Since you are using PQ anyway, why not just do the analysis within PQ? You could enter your substrings into a table or as parameters, and reference them in the PQ Table.Group function where you would count after removing duplicates.

=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((B2:B12="Category "&{1,2})*(C2:C12="Subcategory "&{"1.1","2.1"})),SIGN(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND({"X","Y"},D2:D12)),{1;1}))))
I think SUMPRODUCT makes it unnecessary to use ctrl+shift+enter
SIGN(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND({"X","Y"},D2:D12)),{1;1})) is used create a row wise array if the range D2:D12 contains X and/or Y. 1 for TRUE, 0 for FALSE.
This is matrix multiplied with the (both transposed) category range and subcategory range meeting the criteria.
Or using Office 365:
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E2:E3,B2:B12,F2:F3,C2:C12)*BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"X","Y"},D2:D12)),LAMBDA(b,OR(b))))
Where E2:E3 is the Category and F2:F3 the Subcategory criteria.
And beta channel: =SUM(COUNTIFS(E2:E3,B2:B12,F2:F3,C2:C12)*BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"X","Y"},D2:D12)),OR))

Here's another, longer way to skin the ___ :)
After FINDing P.b.'s
=LET(
    cats, G2:INDEX(G2:G10, COUNTA(G2:G10)),
    subcats, H2:H10,
    subtexts, I2:INDEX(I2:I10, COUNTA(I2:I10)),
    count_row, LAMBDA(row_,
        --AND(
            OR(
                COUNTIFS(
                    INDEX(row_, 1, 2), cats,
                    INDEX(row_, 1, 3), subcats
                )
            ),
            OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(subtexts, INDEX(row_, 1, 4))))
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        "Result",
        SUM(BYROW(A2:INDEX(D2:D1000, COUNTA(A2:A1000)), count_row))
    )
)


Though OR(INDEX(row_, 1, 2) = cats) would also work, with COUNTIF one could use wildcards if needed.
If cat/sub matches are not yielding expected results, try removing spaces with TRIM before comparing.


I would love to know how it performs with your large dataset.
